# onLoad not executing when showModalDialog called in another tab

Tags: javascript, onload, showmodaldialog

**Overview:**
My app detects that the user hasn't done anything for a specific period of time and then loads a dialog with a count down timer on it. This gives the user 2 minutes to react otherwise he is logged off automatically.

I call the count down timer dialog like so:
`window.showModalDialog("/webapp1/html/timeout_popup.htm",items,"dialogHeight: 170px; dialogWidth: 400px; help: 0; status: 0");`

Problem:
The problem is that if the app is running in a different tab (IE 9) to which the user is current focused on then the tab just flashes, but the countdown timer doesn't start until the user clicks on the tab.

I understand that the `body.onLoad` event won't fire until the dialog has been created, but I would like the timer to still count down in the meantime.

I've tried putting alerts inside the `HEAD` & `SCRIPT` tags, but this only fires once I've clicked on the tab.